# Doesnt create tables . Codeigniter DataMapper ORM

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I am new to the DataMapper ORM,
i create a simeple application with Model `User`.
On my controller i write

```
 $u=new User();
  $u->save();
```

but i got eroor,

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'sampleapp.users' doesn't exist

DESCRIBE `users`

Filename: C:\wamp\www\spa\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

how can i set the config, to create all tables.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to create new table via ORM?

Comment: @Nouphal.M yes,does it create table structure based on my model?

Comment: To my knowledge i think not.. this is what they say: Running Save on a new object, one without an ID, will see a new record created for it its `relevant Database table`